# I'm getting This Page Isn't working and that it is redirecting too many times in PHP

Tags: php, authentication, session, redirect

I know that basically the page redirects to a page that redirects to the first page, but for some reason I can't seem to find the errors in my code. Basically if the session is not logged in, go to the login page / do nothing, but if they are logged in redirect them to the index.

```
 if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == null || $_SESSION['loggedin'] == "false") {
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] == "false";
    }
    elseif ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == "true") {
    header('location:index.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the value of `$_SESSION['loggedin']` is a string, not a boolean?

Comment: `$_SESSION['loggedin'] == "false"` is a comparison. You need to use `=` to assign.

Comment: once you are logged in it will always return true. that is why your are getting infinite redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do it like this :)

This is your "index.php" in your system login page:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
header("location:your_dashboard.php"); //your main dashboard
}
?>
```

And this is "your_dashboard.php" in your system:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
header("location: index.php"); //index of your login page
}
?>
```